# How do I become a fan of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

On [this page](http://bikenyn.nationalmssociety.org/site/PageServer?pagename=BIKE_NYN_Social_Networking), it says to [click on this link](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Bike-MS-NYC-Southern-NY/294962363853?ref=ts) and "Become a Fan." I cannot see any link that says *become a fan*. Is this different than simply "Like"-ing a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Like"-ing a page is the new "Being a fan" of a page. Facebook changed the terminology when they introduced the *Like* button to the world.